# Instagram image unsupported size

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have a problem with API call. I would like to get a recent media for an user. I make an API call to following endpoint:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/1638607411/media/recent?count=100&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID

The response is:

…

```
["images":protected]=>
array(3) {
  ["low_resolution"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(114) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/11264735_1688306834723686_1802219154_n.jpg"
    ["width"]=>
    int(320)
    ["height"]=>
    int(320)
  }
  ["thumbnail"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(114) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/11264735_1688306834723686_1802219154_n.jpg"
    ["width"]=>
    int(150)
    ["height"]=>
    int(150)
  }
  ["standard_resolution"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(114) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-15/s612x612/e35/11264735_1688306834723686_1802219154_n.jpg"
    ["width"]=>
    int(612)
    ["height"]=>
    int(612)
  }
}
```

…

I want to use „standard_resolution” image, but it is not working. When I want to get it directly, I received 
Status Code:
404 Unsupported Size

Moreover, when I change "s612x612" in url into "s640x640" - it is working.

Seems like Instagram API bug, I've already reported it, but maybe someone experience something similar?

Answer (score 1):

We noticed this as from Friday August 14 with their realtime API. We did some tests and it seems to be a bug that comes up randomly, only a small subset of responses are wrong, the temporary fix is indeed to replace "s612x612" in the url by "s640x640".

Answer (score 0):

Also encountered this bug today, problem seems to be with the Instagram API. Your fix is the best temporary solution, also submitted a bug report.

Note that your fix - changing the url to expect a 640px square - is returning a 450px square in some of my tests.